# How to receive notification if any process launched/terminated in OS X programatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need to recognise/receive notification if any process launched/terminated in OS X programatically?

Answer (score 0):

NSWorkspace has a couple useful notifications that you can observe, including [`NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification) and [`NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification).

If you need to go further than detecting applications within your control, you need to go somewhat deeper.  Apple has [a technote on how to use kqueues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003081-CH1-SUBSECTION10).  This note shows how to detect when a process quits, and there might be a way to detect when one starts as well.

Comment: It notifies about .app only. What about other system processes?